# VueJs 3 emit event from grand child to his grand parent component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm relatively new to Vue and working on my first project. I'm working on creating a form with several children and grandchildren components.  I ran into an issue where I will need the ability to generate multiple copies of a form.  Therefore I moved some data properties up 1 level.  Currently, the form is ApplicationPage.Vue > TheApplication.Vue > PersonalInformation.Vue > BaseInput.Vue.  My issue is I need to emit changes from PersonalInformation to ApplicationPage passing through TheApplication.  I'm having a hard time figuring out how to handle this situation.  I keep finding solutions for Vue2 but not for Vue3.

**ApplicationPage.vue**

```
template
      <TheApplication :petOptions="petOptions"
                      :stateOptions='stateOptions'
                      v-model="data.primary"
                      applicant="Primary"/>

script
data() {
    return {
      data: {
        primary: {
          personalInformation: {
            first_name: "",
            middle_name: "",
            last_name: "",
            date_of_birth: "",
            phone: null,
            email: "",
            pets: "",
            driver_license: null,
            driver_license_state: "",
            number_of_pets: null,
            additional_comments: ""
          },
        },
      },
    }
  },
```

**TheApplication.Vue**

```
            <personal-information :petOptions="petOptions"
                                  :stateOptions='stateOptions'
                                  :personalInformation="modelValue.personalInformation"
                                  @updateField="UpdateField"
            />
```

```
  methods: {
    UpdateField(field, value) {
      this.$emit('update:modelValue', {...this.modelValue, [field]: value})
    },
```

**PersonalInformation.vue**

```
      <base-input :value="personalInformation.first_name"
                  @change="onInput('personalInformation.first_name', $event.target.value)"
                  label="First Name*"
                  type="text" class=""
                  required/>
```

```
methods: {
    onInput(field, value) {
      console.log(field + " " + value)
      // this.$emit('updateField', { ...this.personalInformation, [field]: value })
      this.$emit('updateField', field, value)
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I would do it: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-cache-l7t10y?file=/src/Grandchild.vue)

Emits only take two parameters, the name of the emit and the value being emitted.  If emitting more than one value you have to emit the values as a single object.
In my solution, the grandchild component emits the field name and the value as a single object

**Grandchild**

```html
<input
    :value="personalInformation.first_name"
    @input="onInput('first_name', $event.target.value)"
    ...
>
```

```js
onInput(field, value) {
  this.$emit("update-field", { field: field, value: value });
},
```

Which the child object catches and re-emits, **but** first takes care to emit in the format expected by the parent component (it expects the entire `data.primary` object since that is what was set as the v-model)

**Child**

```html
<grandchild
    :personalInformation="modelValue.personalInformation"
    @updateField="UpdateField"
  />
```

```js
UpdateField({ field, value }) {
  const newVal = this.modelValue;
  newVal.personalInformation[field] = value;
  this.$emit("update:modelValue", newVal);
}
```

The parent component then automatically receives and updates the v-model `data.primary` object.

*Alternatively*, I have to mention that instead of dealing with any emitting / passing down objects between multiple levels of components, you can always use [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/), the official state management library for Vue (save some state in one component, read same state from any other component).  There's of course a learning curve but it's definitely worth learning and is made to simplify exactly this type of situation.

Comment: Thank you!   I was about to use state management but I felt like it was overkill since the data was only needed in a direct line.

Comment: Is there a way I can add an additional parameter to @updateField="UpdateField"?   I have 2 other children components that have arrays in them and I need to pass the index position so I can update the correct field.

Comment: @Mwheeler91 yeah, a store can be quite overkill here. As for an additional param, you can add pretty much what you want to `newVal`. Bring any variables you want down there, you're not required to use only what's `UpdateField` is receiving (`field` + `value`).

Answer (score 5):

For anyone that doesn't want to chain event emits, there is the parent object on the child which can be used to emit an event as well. Be sure to register the emits in the parent to avoid warnings in the console.

#### Child

Call the immediate parent's `$emit` here.

**Child.vue**

```
<input @input="$parent.$emit('custom-event', e.target.value) />
```

Or using methods:

```
<input @input="handleInput" />
```

```
export default {
  methods: {
    handleInput(e) {
      this.$parent.$emit('custom-event', e.target.value)
    }
  }
}
```

#### Parent

Since it's the parent that does the emitting to the ancestor, declare the emits here. For `<script setup>`, simply use the `defineEmits()` method to declare emits. See the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#declaring-emitted-events).

**Parent.vue**

```
<Child /> <!-- No need to listen to the event here -->
```

```
export default {
   emits: ['custom-event'] // Register the emits
}
```

If using `<script setup>`

```
<script setup>
  defineEmits(['custom-event']) // Register the emits
</script>
```

#### Grandparent

Then listen to the event in the grandparent component.

**GrandParent.vue**

```
 <Parent @custom-event="doSomething()" /> <!-- The event is being listened to in the grandparent component -->
```